# Using pyzipcodes to create a States column from Zip Code column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, mapping, zipcode

I have a dataframe called df1. It includes a zip code column (ie., includes zip codes) and I want to use the pyzipcodes library to create a new column called state, and map the zip codes to states. Does anyone have an idea how to call on and use the pyzipcodes and achieve this task?

I was able to get entries in the state could that look like "ZipCode(zip='85711', city='Tucson', state='AZ'..." but I just want to extract the relevant state with the zip code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`pandas.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) to map the column of zipcodes with the *ZipCode* object (that is basically a dictionnary) created by [`pyzipcode`](https://pypi.org/project/pyzipcode/).

```
from pyzipcode import ZipCodeDatabase

zcdb = ZipCodeDatabase()

df["state"] = df["zp"].map(lambda x: zcdb[x].state)
```

Output :

```
print(df)

      zp state
0  85711    AZ
```